# c99 dynamic array

Tags: arrays, dynamic, c99

I'm writing a very small, project-specific OpenGLES engine for iphone and I really need to use a good, solid, and proven dynamic array library/macro in c99 dialect. (No C++, Obj-C, stl whatsoever)

It's strongly necessary for render batch and polygon mesh, so it should be able to handle various types of data, and additionally causes minimal overhead when array size changes and new data is inserted.

I've been searching around and found two candidates for my need.

the first one is from [ccCArray](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/unofficial-cocos2d-api-reference/html/cc_c_array_8h.html) from Cocos2d.

and another one is [utarray](http://uthash.sourceforge.net/utarray.html) written by Troy D. Hanson.

ccCArray IS rock solid, thoroughly proven by community. utarray looks fine but I cannot find anyone actually uses it.

Any more suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

A library ?! A C++ template would be more than suitable for this need. I'd say about AT MOST 15 functions (excluding alternative constructors and const getters), and you're done. Also able to use it for ANY type, ANY size and ANY size type (byte, int etc.) And it's just one file: a .h or, better said, a .hpp
Any reason you're rejecting it ? Seems like you want to make life harder for yourself :)

Comment: I think that would make more sense as a comment, since it doesn't really answer the question as it was asked.

Comment: fair enough, sadly it won't let me comment yet... pfft.